# I softbricked my china tab

Tags: unbricking

I bootlooped my tab and forgot to turn on debugging option. I used framaroot for rooting. Only way to make my tab go back to normal is by factory resetting through recovery mode, but my Power button isn't working.

I have an HKC Q79 tablet (in the box it says the model is an H8 but its actually a Q79) any idea how to bring it back to normal?

Answer (score 0):

Heres a simple solution to that:

1. Download and install Shuame from http://www.shuame.com/ 
   Its an app is full of android tools.Its in Chinese, though.
2. Install your tablet's device drivers. Youll have to find these according to the chipset your tablet uses as many chineses tabs and phones pretty much dont exist on the internet and so, youll have to search by chipset. Its probably by Mediatek.
3. Connect your tab to the PC and launch shuame.If your tablet isn't detected automatically, click on the blue button next to the phone icon in the main page.
   4.Once your tablet is detected, click on the icon with foure squares on it in the navigation tab.
4. Click on the button on the left column with the phone icon and the text "recovery.

That should get your tablet to recovery mode.